# Stating where images were obtained from, recommended/required?

Tags: copyright, author

I was wondering if it's required or recommended to display the owner/source of any images used on my website?

If I were to use a general image from another website (not necessarily having a specific license attached to it), do I need to state where I obtained the image from? And if so, **is there a professional or accepted way to do this** (maybe an acknowledgements page or similar)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The warning part :**
Using copyrighted material on a website without the right of using it isn't a good idea. It could be fine for several years and you would be super happy, your website would have grown etc. And then on day, in the mailbox, you'll find that letter saying you've used a copyrighted picture for X years, so you'll have to pay x xxxx,xx$ for using it. Be aware this could happen (I've seen that in a french TV show called "La facture").

---

With that in mind, **does a big part of your images came from the same source ?** If it's a free images library or something like that, you could look there to find some statement of what you've to do if you use site's images. I've personally seen one asking you to state somewhere on your site that the images came from their site. Finding something similar could give you a good idea of what you should do.

**Case 1 : If they came from a little amount of sources**, it would be nice to make a single page stating from where they came from as it could be combined with other statement relative to your site's policies, copyright, etc. It would also be cleaner as you won't pollute your entire site with copyright notices (that would be almost the same every time anyway)

**Case 2 : If images came from maaaaany different sources**, I would consider making a little front end script (with JavaScript) fired at the "onload" event of the page. It would search for all images in your DOM and each one having a custom attribute you'll have created (something like "copyright-owner") would receive a little over effect (a tool-tip or a square of text appearing on the image) telling from where this image came from.